# How to use a variable as a Key Value in PHP array?

Tags: php

I want to use `$par_id = '31512071';` variable in PHP `array();` function.

I tried using  `"par_id" => $par_id` instead of `"par_id" => 31512071` in the following php code, but it didn't work. How can i use the variable inside `array();` method?

```
$par_id = '31512071';

$params = array(
   "parcelNum" => "315-12-071",
   "b_2" => "Search",
   "opts"=>"2",
   "txtPageSize" => 10,
   "par_id" => 31512071
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it didn't work`? Did you dump the variable with `var_dump()` to determine if the variable was correctly parsed or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
$par_id = '31512071';

$params = array(
   "parcelNum" => "315-12-071",
   "b_2" => "Search",
   "opts"=>"2",
   "txtPageSize" => 10,
   "par_id" => "{$par_id}"
);
```

Comment: Actually it's the same as `"par_id" => $par_id`